Unable to serve media Files on production environment
I'm trying to deploy my django app on the render, but confronted a problem when I set DEBUG=FALSE.
My media files, which are uploaded by using admin interface through the models' imagefield, are unable to show.
I think the problem exists within my nginx settings and django setting. However, I've tryied several times but still unable to fix the problme.
I set nginx.conf:
http {
include mime.types;

server {
    listen 80;
    root C:/Users/USER/Desktop/onemoretime;

    # location / {
    #     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # }

    location /static/ {
        alias C:/Users/USER/Desktop/onemoretime/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias C:/Users/USER/Desktop/onemoretime/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  # 代理到 Waitress
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

}
events {}
and django setting:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

in this way.
I think nginx should be able to deal with and serve all the media files, but the thing is the other way around.
I use whitenoise to deal with static file, so my problem is basically about media file. I've tried several hours but failed finding out what goes wrong.
I'll be really thankful if someone know why the problem arise and how to fix it. Thank you so much.

What error do you get when you open http://.../media/file_that_should_exists?

@mx0 Hello, thank yout for asking. I got a 404 not found error

Make sure you have below config in django settings:
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Nginx Config below

# media file
location /media {
        alias /var/www/project/media; <production project path>
}

# Django static file
location /static {
        alias /var/www/project/static; <production project path>
}

Important: Make sure you have ran **python manage.py collectstatic** command on production server to serve the file from Nginx.


Hello, thank you for answering. But I have some questions. First, should I use: MEDIA_URL = '/media' or MEDIA_URL = '/media/' and what's the difference? Second, right now my project is deployed on render, so the address is like: "https://onemoretimecroissant.onrender.com/"，should I write my locattion on nginx like:
location /media {
alias var/www/onemoretimecroissant.onrender/media/;
}
this?
And by the way, I use whitenoise for static file,so my problem is basicly media file.
Thank you so much.

The trailing slash at the end of '/media/' is important because Django expects URLs to be formatted with a trailing slash. It helps ensure that the URL resolves correctly when combined with file paths.
print working directory (pwd) ---> enter this command in your working directory to get a absolute path same you can copy paste in location /media { alias var/www/onemoretimecroissant.onrender/media

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Maybe you are missing this in your main settings urls.py
